# How do I make that all `dashboard` pages are passed `isAdmin` check using `SessionProvider`?

Tags: authentication, next.js, next.js13

I have 3 routes:

- /dashboard
- /dashboard/support
- /dashboard/admin

I want to pass all 3 routes a prop from the top called `isAdmin`. `isAdmin` is a boolean to make sure only admins access `/dashboard/admin` route.

It uses swr:

```js
import useSWRImmutable from "swr/immutable"

const fetcher = (...args: [any]) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json())

export const useAdminStatus = () => {
    const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWRImmutable(`/api/admin`, fetcher)

    return {
        data,
        error,
        isLoading,
    }
}
```

How do I pass it now that I don't have `_app.tsx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a `useAdminStatus` hook.

#### src/app/hooks/useAdminStatus.tsx

```js
import useSWRImmutable from "swr/immutable"

const fetcher = (...args: [any]) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json())

export const useAdminStatus = () => {
    const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWRImmutable(`/api/admin`, fetcher)

    return {
        data,
        error,
        isLoading,
    }
}
```

I hide the specific navs that only admins can access like this.

#### src/app/components/dashboard/Nav.tsx

```js
"use client"

import clsx from "clsx"
import Link from "next/link"
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation"

import { useAdminStatus } from "@app/hooks/useAdminStatus"

interface NavLinkProps {
    href: string
    title: string
    isActive: boolean
}

const NavLink = ({ href, title, isActive }: NavLinkProps) => {
    return (
        <Link
            href={href}
            className={clsx("relative block px-3 py-3 transition hover:text-teal-500", {
                "text-teal-400 underline underline-offset-8": isActive,
            })}
        >
            {title}
        </Link>
    )
}

export const Nav = () => {
    const { data } = useAdminStatus()
    const pathName = usePathname()

    const navLinks: NavLinkProps[] = [
        {
            href: "/dashboard",
            title: "Dashboard",
            isActive: pathName === "/dashboard",
        },
        {
            href: "/dashboard/support",
            title: "Support",
            isActive: pathName === "/dashboard/support",
        },
        {
            href: "/dashboard/admin",
            title: "Admin",
            isActive: pathName === "/dashboard/admin",
        },
    ]

    return (
        <ul className="m-auto flex rounded-full bg-slate-800 px-3 text-sm font-medium text-slate-200 shadow-lg shadow-slate-800/5 ring-1 ring-slate-900/5 backdrop-blur">
            {navLinks.map((link) => {
                if (link.title === "Admin" && !data?.isAdmin) {
                    return null
                }
                return (
                    <li key={link.href}>
                        <NavLink href={link.href} title={link.title} isActive={link.isActive} />
                    </li>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

And I redirect if someone is not an admin like this.

#### src/app/components/dashboard/AdminComponent.tsx

```js
"use client"

import { redirect } from "next/navigation"
import React from "react"

import { UploadPDF } from "@app/components/dashboard/UploadPDF"
import { useAdminStatus } from "@app/hooks/useAdminStatus"

// eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
export const AdminComponent = React.memo(() => {
    const { data, error, isLoading } = useAdminStatus()

    if (isLoading) return null
    if (error) return <span className="text-slate-500">Failed to load `AdminComponent`</span>

    if (!data.isAdmin) redirect("/dashboard")

    return <UploadPDF />
})
```